# access device thow adb with USB debug off

Tags: adb, usb-debugging

I have an acer iconia tab 7 and the touch screen is dead.

It as no custom recovery, root or custom rom.

I was able to factory reset him throw the factory recovery but now im just stuck on the "select language" menu.

I know that by default stock roms bring usb debug off.

Im running debian 8.6. How can i turn it on so i can use adb?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no way to turn adb on in this case.

But if your device support **OTG** you can try to use mouse to select all necessary things (may be on your device it will work before final settings of Android system will be accepted (language and other))

Comment: doesnt support OTG